# How to add a listener to a button from a ActionListener inner class?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, inner-classes

I'm trying to do a simple calculator program by building my swing interface on netbeans.

I want to have 3 Classes:

1. GUI Class - which holds the codes for building the interface
2. Listener Class - holds all the listener in the GUI interface
3. Boot Class - this will start the application

For simplicity, I will post my code for a single button. My goal here is to change the Buttons visible text from "1" to "11" to test my design. After verifying that my design works I will continue on working on other buttons.

calculatorGUI.class

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class calculatorGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public calculatorGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
oneBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
oneBtn.setText("1");
}

private javax.swing.JButton oneBtn;

public JButton getOneBtn() {
    return oneBtn;
}

public void setOneBtn(String name) {
    oneBtn.setText(name);
}
}
```

Listener.class

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Listener {

class oneBtnListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
       calculatorGUI g = new calculatorGUI();
       g.setOneBtn("11");
   }

}
```

}

Boot.class

```
public class Boot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     calculatorGUI gui = new calculatorGUI();
     Listener listen = new Listener();
     Listener.oneBtnListener oneListen = listen.new oneBtnListener();
     gui.getOneBtn().addActionListener(oneListen);
     gui.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

The problem is, nothing happens when I click the button. It seems that the actionListener is not being registered to the button. Can I ask for your help guys on which angle I missed?

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I am seeing is how you are initializing `calculatorGUI` twice, once with the default value and another with the changed value. Take out the initialization of `calculatorGUI` within your Listener class and pass it from your `Boot class` and it should work fine.

Although if I were you, I would add the GUI implementations within the GUI class, having it within the listener class that is using within the main function is not something I have seen before and would probably not advise.

Comment: How do I exactly pass my calculatorGUI instance from my Boot class to my Listener class?

Comment: Honestly the work around to do so is so tedious that I just suggest simply putting everything except your initialization of the calculatorGUI in main. It is good coding practice and will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code accordingly,

```
class Listener {

class oneBtnListener implements ActionListener {
   @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
      if(ev.getActionCommand() == "1")
      {
          JButton btn = (JButton)ev.getSource();
          btn.setText("11");
      }
  }

}
}

class calculatorGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public calculatorGUI() {
   initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
oneBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
oneBtnListener btnListener = new Listener().new oneBtnListener();
oneBtn.setText("1");
oneBtn.setBounds(100,100,100,25);
oneBtn.addActionListener(btnListener);
add(oneBtn);

setLayout(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(400,400);
}

private javax.swing.JButton oneBtn;

public JButton getOneBtn() {
   return oneBtn;
}

public void setOneBtn(String name) {
   oneBtn.setText(name);
}
}
```

> You can change now other part according to your requirement, I just
>   gave you "1" -> "11", but you can do more.
>
> Best of Luck.